# How do I append a byte[] to a List<Byte>?

Tags: java

How do I append the elements of a `byte[]` to a `List<Byte>`?

Comment: So you want a `List` of Byte arrays or do you want to convert a byte array into a `List` of bytes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com), you could use [Bytes.asList(byte...)](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release09/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Bytes.html#asList%28byte...%29) like this:

```
List<Byte> list = ...
byte[] bytes = ...
list.addAll(Bytes.asList(bytes));
```

Answer (score 8):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
for(byte b : byte) {
    list.add(b);
}
```